# Distance of Points Within a Circle Relative to Center

Tags: r, geometry, coordinates, distance

I'm having a little difficulty with calculating the distances of points within a circle relative to the circle's center in R. After calculating the distances of uniformly distributed points with my function (see below for a full example), I then subset the data based on a distance cutoff. When plotted, the result is not a uniform ring as one might intuit. Instead, the result is a strangely shaped object that's "almost" a ring but pinched along the horizontal axis.

I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but I cannot fathom what it could be.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(111)

# Generate a set of angles from a uniform distribution
theta <- runif(2500, 0, 2 * pi)

# Generate a set of radii from a uniform distribution 
radius <- sqrt(runif(2500))

# Assemble into a matrix of 2D coordinates
x <- radius * cos(theta)
y <- radius * sin(theta)
z <- cbind(x, y)

par(pty = "s") # square plot region
plot.diameter <- c(-1, 1) # plot boundaries
plot(z, pch = 20, cex = 0.20,
     col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5),
     xlim = plot.diameter, ylim = plot.diameter)
```

[image]

```
# Radial distance function
# Computes the distance of all points within the circle to the circle center 
# Default center: (0, 0)
rad.dist <- function(m, x.center = 0, y.center = 0) {
  (m[, 1] - x.center) ^ 2 + (m[, 2] - y.center) ^ 2 %>%
    sqrt() -> d
  return(d)
}

z.radial <- rad.dist(z)

# Bind radial distance column to coordinates
z <- cbind(z[, 1], z[, 2], z.radial)

# Rename columns for convenience
colnames(z) <- c("x", "y", "rd")

# Subset based on radial distance
outer.ring <- subset(z, z[, 3] >= 0.75)

plot(outer.ring, pch = 20, cex = 0.20,
     col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5),
     xlim = plot.diameter, ylim = plot.diameter)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of operations in `rad.dist()` is the main problem. In particular that of the `magrittr` pipe is throwing you for a loop. `1 + 2 %>% sqrt` vs `(1 + 2) %>% sqrt`.

```
rad.dist <- function(m, x.center = 0, y.center = 0) {
  sqrt((m[, 1] - x.center)^2 + (m[, 2] - y.center)^2)
}

outer.ring <- z[rad.dist(z) >= 0.75,]

plot(outer.ring, pch = 20, cex = 0.20,
     col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5),
     xlim = plot.diameter, ylim = plot.diameter)
```

Comment: It seems that my "tidy" coding efforts got me this time. I really appreciate everyone looking at my problem!

Answer (score 2):

That's because your points are not uniformly distributed in the circle.

To generate uniform points in a circle (more generally, a sphere), you can use the `uniformly` package:

```
library(uniformly)

npoints <- 2500
z <- runif_in_sphere(npoints, d = 2, r = 1)

rad.dist <- function(m, x.center = 0, y.center = 0) {
  sqrt((m[, 1] - x.center) ^ 2 + (m[, 2] - y.center) ^ 2)
}
z.radial <- rad.dist(z)
# Bind radial distance column to coordinates
z <- cbind(z[, 1], z[, 2], z.radial)
# Rename columns for convenience
colnames(z) <- c("x", "y", "rd")
# Subset based on radial distance
outer.ring <- subset(z, z[, 3] >= 0.75)
# plot
par(pty = "s")
plot(outer.ring, pch = 20, cex = 0.20,
     col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5),
     xlim = c(-1,1), ylim = c(-1,1))
```

[image]

If your goal is to get uniform points in the annulus, you can directly generate them with `uniformly`:

```
z <- runif_in_annulus(1000, c(0,0), 0.75, 1)
plot(z, pch = 20, cex = 0.20,
     col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5),
     xlim = c(-1,1), ylim = c(-1,1))
```

Comment: Hmm... no sorry I don't understand. The way you use to generate uniformly in the circle [is correct](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html).

Comment: This is a nice package! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

`%>%` has a higher order of precedence than `+`. You need parentheses around your `x^2 + y^2` before the pipe and `sqrt`.

```
> library(magrittr)     # or dplyr, or anywhere it's reexported
> 2+2 %>% sqrt()
[1] 3.414214
> (2+2) %>% sqrt()
[1] 2
> 2 + (2 %>% sqrt())
[1] 3.414214
```

Comment: A nice demo of the problem! That was the source of my strange output.